# Switch Case menu isn't being executed

Tags: java

I have a piece of code that is suposed to print the whole menu, and then provide the user to choose from the options given. After the menu is printed (like this):

```
System.out.println("VCP ­ Ver a conversa em progresso");
System.out.println("PNM ­ Publicar nova mensagem ");
System.out.println("PME - Publicar mensagem encriptada");
System.out.println("CMA - Corrigir mensagem anterior");
System.out.println("ECP - Encerrar conversa em progresso");
System.out.println("MCA - Mostrar conversas anteriores");
System.out.println("A - Ajuda");
System.out.println("S - Sair");
```

I need to make a Switch-Case for the user to be able to choose an option:

```
String menu = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(menu);
  switch(menu){
    case "VCP":
        System.out.println("VCP P");
        break;
    case "PNM":
        System.out.println("PNM");
        break;
    case "PME":
        meuProjecto.PME();
        break;
    case "CMA":
        meuProjecto.CMA();
        break;
    case "ECP":
        meuProjecto.ECP();
    case "MCA":
        meuProjecto.MCA();
        break;
    case "A":
        System.out.println("VCP ­ Ver a conversa em progresso");
        System.out.println("PNM ­ Publicar nova mensagem ");
        System.out.println("PME - Publicar mensagem encriptada");
        System.out.println("CMA - Corrigir mensagem anterior");
        System.out.println("ECP - Encerrar conversa em progresso");
        System.out.println("MCA - Mostrar conversas anteriores");
        System.out.println("A - Ajuda");
        System.out.println("S - Sair");
        break;
    }
```

Now, the problem is: The initial menu is printed, but then the program ends. I get no error messages, nor any kind of warning. I am using version 1.8.
Please note that i am new to the community and programming in general. Any kind of help will be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently, the user input is a string not listed in the switch-case.

Comment: You need to read the user's respond into a variable. In your case, it would be the easiest way to wrap the whole code you posted in some kind of loop and add an option to end the program in your menu (maybe you have this already, I do not understand the language you use for your output).

Comment: I would also prefer to program the menu like that, but this is an algorithm for school, and they demanded to be like this...

Comment: You are suposed to write: "VCP" or "CMA". Those options are listed in the Switch Case.

Comment: Have you verified the input string is what you think it is? What debugging steps have you taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

- a looping code;
- with an exit option;
- with an option to deal with invalid input.

```css
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste {

public static void main(String args[]) {

MeuProjecto meuProjecto = new MeuProjecto();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean sair = false;
while (!sair) {

    String menu = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(menu);
    switch(menu){
        case "VCP":
            System.out.println("VCP P");
            break;
        case "PNM":
            System.out.println("PNM");
            break;
        case "PME":
            meuProjecto.PME();
            break;
        case "CMA":
            meuProjecto.CMA();
            break;
        case "ECP":
            meuProjecto.ECP();
        case "MCA":
            meuProjecto.MCA();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Opção inválida!");
        case "A": 
            System.out.println("VCP ­ Ver a conversa em progresso");
            System.out.println("PNM ­ Publicar nova mensagem ");
            System.out.println("PME - Publicar mensagem encriptada");
            System.out.println("CMA - Corrigir mensagem anterior");
            System.out.println("ECP - Encerrar conversa em progresso");
            System.out.println("MCA - Mostrar conversas anteriores");
            System.out.println("A - Ajuda");
            System.out.println("S - Sair");
            break;
        case "S":
            sair = true;
    }

}

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Not exactly the way it was told, but it doesn't matter. It's stupid anyway. Thank you very much :)